# R adding to a list (nested list)

Tags: r, list, nested, addition

I have list1:

```
 list1<-list("outliers"=list("values"=list(list(c("a","b","c"),
                                           "dimensionKey"=2101120,
                                           "metric"="1")
                                      )
                        )
        )

 > list1
$outliers
$outliers$values
$outliers$values[[1]]
$outliers$values[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$outliers$values[[1]]$dimensionKey
[1] 2101120

$outliers$values[[1]]$metric
[1] "1"
```

I need to add into this list values:

```
list2<-list(c("e", "f", "g", "m"),
 "dimensionKey"=2101120,
 "metric"="2")
```

I want rezult to look:

```
   $outliers
   $outliers$values
   $outliers$values[[1]]
   $outliers$values[[1]][[1]]
   [1] "a" "b" "c"

   $outliers$values[[1]]$dimensionKey
   [1] 2101120

   $outliers$values[[1]]$metric
   [1] "1"

   $outliers$values[[2]]
   $outliers$values[[2]][[1]]
   [1] "e" "f" "g" "m"

   $outliers$values[[2]]$dimensionKey
   [1] 2101120

   $outliers$values[[2]]$metric
   [1] "2"
```

How can I manage that?

P.S.: I need that for my function for adding in existing list values, therefore I can't write this in one step.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
list1$outliers$values <- append(list1$outliers$values, list(list2))
```

The result (`list1`):

```
$outliers
$outliers$values
$outliers$values[[1]]
$outliers$values[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$outliers$values[[1]]$dimensionKey
[1] 2.10112e+06

$outliers$values[[1]]$metric
[1] "1"


$outliers$values[[2]]
$outliers$values[[2]][[1]]
[1] "e" "f" "g" "m"

$outliers$values[[2]]$dimensionKey
[1] 2.10112e+06

$outliers$values[[2]]$metric
[1] "2"
```

Comment: Thank you for idea! But how to made last few rows to look like mine:

$outliers$values[[2]]$dimensionKey
? Your answer is without [[2]] after $values

Comment: @user3227114 Sorry, now the solution is much simpler.